# It's there a way to archived Jira Issue and worklog

Tags: jira

i try to find a way to archive project, issue and worklogs from JIRA to another database to increase performance.

It's there a way to transfer all old "items" who was not modified past a year?

Comment: 1) Why do you think this will increase performance? 2) Have you asked Atlassian support? Vendor support should always be your first reference before coming here.

Comment: It's not just increase performance of the software, but performance of the staff to. A cleanup of the interface we actually have over 400 projects, and over 55k issues. Around 300K of worklog.

Comment: Yes i ask attlasian support and I am waiting an answer from us. All my report are very slow cause there are lot of data ("old data")

Answer (score 0):

You can move a project to a different instance following the procedure explained in this link:

https://awnaba.atlassian.net/wiki/display/PCP/Moving+a+project+to+another+instance

Basically, it consists of moving first the project configuration with a third-party plugin called [Project Configurator](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.awnaba.projectconfigurator.projectconfigurator/server/overview). This plugin is able to export the configuration of a project to an XML file and restoring it into another instance based on that file. Finally, you would have to import project issues and their data with JIRA Project Import Tool. This tool works with an XML backup from the source JIRA instance.